# Const qualifier and forward reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Have seen this code in the [seastar](https://github.com/scylladb/seastar/blob/master/core/task.hh) framework

```
template <typename Func>
class lambda_task final : public task {
    Func _func;
public:
    lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, const Func& func) : task(sg), 
    _func(func) {}
    lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, Func&& func) : task(sg), 
    _func(std::move(func)) {}
    virtual void run_and_dispose() noexcept override {
        _func();
        delete this;
    }
};

template <typename Func>
inline std::unique_ptr<task> make_task(Func&& func) {
    return std::make_unique<lambda_task<Func>>(current_scheduling_group(), 
    std::forward<Func>(func));
}
```

`using scheduling_group = int;`
`auto current_scheduling_group(){ return int{};}`//for simplicity

let us assume I am going to instantiate `task` like below

```
 auto work = [](){...}
 make_task(work);
```

so since the `work` is an `lvalue` `make_task(Func&&)`->`make_task(Func&)` and it instantiate `lambda_task` as `lambda_task<Func&>` which causes these two ctors

```
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, const Func& func)
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, Func&& func)
```

to become(I assume it would)

```
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, **const Func& func**)
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, **Func& func**)
```

the instantiation of `lambda_task` with `work` object is throwing a compile-time error

```
<source>:127:5: error: 'lambda_task<Func>::lambda_task(scheduling_group, Func&&) [with Func = main()::<lambda()>&; scheduling_group = int]' 
cannot be overloaded with 'lambda_task<Func>::lambda_task(scheduling_group, const Func&) [with Func = main()::<lambda()>&; scheduling_group = int]'

     lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, Func&& func) : task(sg), _func(std::move(func)) {}

     ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:126:5: note: previous declaration 'lambda_task<Func>::lambda_task(scheduling_group, const Func&) 
[with Func = main()::<lambda()>&; scheduling_group = int]'
```

and what I did to make it work is I've changed

```
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, Func&& func) to
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, std::remove_reference_t<Func>&& func)
```

question 1: was I right or wrong? will my change break anything? or it is needed?

I realized that the

```
 lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, const Func& func)#1
 lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, Func && func)#2
```

`#1 & #2` is conflicting and moreover adding `&&`to `Func` doesn't make it as an `rvalue` as it was reference collapsed to `lvalue`(so I used std::remove_reference_t )

question 2: 
assume `T&&` is a forward reference [T=int] and collapsed into `T&`.
why `std::is_same<const int&, const T&>` isn't true?

```
<source>:162:5:   required from 'void maketest(T&&) [with T = int&]'
<source>:154:18: error: static assertion failed
static_assert(std::is_same<const int&,const T&>::value,"");
```

why adding `const` to a collapsed reference isn't taking any effect?

or my observation is wrong?

Comment: Adding const to a reference never has any effect, because references can't be rebound anyway.  Reference collapsing doesn't reach inside and change modifiers on the referent.

Comment: Ben, appreciate if you could make some more brief about it, I couldn't get that  "references can't be rebound" statement

Comment: By no rebound of reference, `int i = 42; int& ref = i; int j = 0;` you cannot make `ref`points to `j` as you might have do with pointer (`int* p = &i; p = &j;`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for `template <typename T> class lambda_task`, with `lambda_task<F&>`,
we have

- `const T&` = `T const&` = `F&`
- and `T&&` = `F&`.

You probably want to decay both `T` to have respectively `const F&` and `F&&`:

```
lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, const std::decay_t<Func>& func) : task(sg), _func(func) {}

lambda_task(scheduling_group sg, std::decay_t<Func>&& func) : task(sg), _func(std::move(func)) {}
```

Comment: Why does `const T&` (= `const F& &`) = `F&`? Is it part of the reference collapsing rules or how does this work?

Comment: True, this is what I've thought, since we are explicitly mentioning what references to take we need either remove_ref... Or decay_t on type T  in this case

Comment: @Aldarrion: see [reference_collapsing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlcpp1313.aix.doc/language_ref/reference_collapsing.html) for example.

Comment: @Aldarrion Lets use East const to make it easier to understand: `const T&` --east const--> `T const&`. now we substitue F&: `T const&` --substitute F& for T--> `F& const&`. in plain words its: a reference to a const reference to a F. But a reference itself  is always const, so we can omit that: `F & &`. now its a reference to a reference to F. and a reference to a reference is just a reference. so its just `F&`. Overall the table linked by Jarod42 has all the details, just without explainations.